# String data getting truncated when fetching through sql datareader

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sqldatasource

I am using a **datareader** to fetch a table's record values through a *stored proc*.
but while using ***datareader.getstring(2)*** to fetch the value of the particular column, the string returned is **truncated** ( rest of **getstrings** are returning complete values).
Can anyone guide me in analyzing this?

Comment: You need to show us the stored proc code, maybe the values is returned as varchar(x) x smaller than the length of the actual column length?

Answer (score 2):

The XML data row is truncated at 2,033 characters when you use the SqlDataReader object. To resolve this problem, use the ExecuteXmlReader method to read FOR XML queries. For additional information about how to use ExecuteXmlReader with SQL Server FOR XML queries
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310378
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316701

Answer (score 0):

Change your Db logic as following,

```
Declare @xmldata xml
set @xmldata =(<your select query>  
FOR XML AUTO)
select @xmldata as returnXml
```

And read column **returnXml** from c# i.e. objReader[0]